# My java while loop is not returning back the weekly pay

Tags: java, while-loop

Okay so part two on this.  I restructured the code on this but now I can't figure out a way to return back the empWeeklyPay without initializing it to zero.  And if I initialize it to zero then my pay will always be zero?  Can anyone think of anything I can do?

```
public double getWeeklyPay()//Call the getWeeklyHours method of the Emp's timecard to      get the total
//hours worked and then multiply the returned value by the emp's hourly rate and return the value.
{
TimeCard empTimeCard = timeCard;
double empWeeklyPay;
double totalOtHours;
double totalRegHours;
int i = 0;

while(i <= empTimeCard.NUMDAYS && empTimeCard.getHoursByDay(i) > 8)
{
double empHourlyRate = getHourlyRate();
double otHours = 0;
double regHours = 0;
double sumOtHours = 0;
int sumRegHours = 0;

//grabbing the overtime and reghours and storing them
otHours = empTimeCard.getHoursByDay(i) % 8;
regHours = empTimeCard.getHoursByDay(i) - otHours;
sumOtHours += otHours;
sumRegHours += regHours;
double tmpBasePay = (sumRegHours * empHourlyRate) + (sumOtHours * empHourlyRate * 1.5);

if(Integer.toString(getEmployeeId()).charAt(0) == '0' || Integer.toString(getEmployeeId()).charAt(0) == '2'
|| Integer.toString(getEmployeeId()).charAt(0) == '9')
//Java reads in 1010 so need to convert to a string to do a count on the value.
{
  tmpBasePay += (tmpBasePay * .10);        
  i++;
}
else if(Integer.toString(getEmployeeId()).charAt(0) == '3')
{
  tmpBasePay -= (tmpBasePay *.10);
  i++;
}
else if(Integer.toString(getEmployeeId()).charAt(0) == '8')
{ 
  tmpBasePay += (tmpBasePay * .20);
  i++;
}
totalRegHours = regHours;
totalOtHours = sumOtHours;
if(totalRegHours > 34)
{
tmpBasePay -= (tmpBasePay * .06);
//empWeeklyPay = tmpBasePay;
empWeeklyPay = tmpBasePay;
}
else
{
empWeeklyPay = tmpBasePay;
}
```

}

```
return empWeeklyPay;// <---need to return back this value.
```

Comment: That's a *lot* of `return` statements. If the idea is to actually loop, you're failing to do so, because you `return` after incrementing `i`, thus stopping the loop.

Comment: Please fix your formatting.  The code is impossible to read as-is.

Comment: Ah okay I figured the return was screwing it up..ok let me change that..

Comment: Ok Jim let me try to fix the formatting as well..

Comment: I've edited that code now..thanks for alerting me that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question. I was able to figure it out. Please see code below in case someone else faces this same problem in the near or distant future:

```
public double getWeeklyPay() {
// Call the getWeeklyHours method of the Emp's timecard to get the total hours worked
// and then multiply the returned value by the emp's hourly rate and return the value.

double empWeeklyPay;
double sumOtHours = 0;
double sumRegHours = 0;
int i = 0;


while(i < getTimeCard().NUMDAYS) {
// grabbing the overtime and regHours and storing them

    double otHours = 0;
    double regHours = 0;
    otHours += getTimeCard().getHoursByDay(i);
    regHours += getTimeCard().getHoursByDay(i) - otHours;
    sumOtHours += otHours;
    sumRegHours += regHours;
    i++;
}    

empWeeklyPay = (sumRegHours * getHourlyRate()) + (sumOtHours * getHourlyRate() * 1.5);

if(Integer.toString(getEmployeeId()).charAt(0) == '0' || Integer.toString(getEmployeeId()).charAt(0) == '2'
|| Integer.toString(getEmployeeId()).charAt(0) == '9') {
// Java reads in 1010 so need to convert to a string to do a count on the value.

    double tmpBasePay = (sumRegHours * getHourlyRate()) + (sumOtHours * getHourlyRate() * 1.5);  
    tmpBasePay += (tmpBasePay * .10); 
    empWeeklyPay = tmpBasePay;
}

else if(Integer.toString(getEmployeeId()).charAt(0) == '3') {
  double tmpBasePay = (sumRegHours * getHourlyRate()) + (sumOtHours * getHourlyRate() * 1.5);
    tmpBasePay -= (tmpBasePay * .10);
    empWeeklyPay = tmpBasePay;
}

else if(Integer.toString(getEmployeeId()).charAt(0) == '8') { 
    double tmpBasePay = (sumRegHours * getHourlyRate()) + (sumOtHours * getHourlyRate() * 1.5);  
    tmpBasePay += (tmpBasePay * .20);
    empWeeklyPay = tmpBasePay;
}

if(sumRegHours > 34) {
    empWeeklyPay -= (empWeeklyPay * .06 );
    return empWeeklyPay;
}

else
    return empWeeklyPay;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first `while` loop while only do one iteration as it always encounters a `return` keyword. `return` will get you off the `while` loop **and** your `getWeekPay()` method.

You just need to return your `empWeeklyPay` variable at the end of your method, so only the last return is useful here. The end of your method should look like:

```
if(RegHours > 34) {
    empBasePay -= (empBasePay * .06);
    empWeeklyPay = empBasePay;
} else {
    empWeeklyPay = empBasePay;
}
return empWeeklyPay;
```

**EDIT**

Why you're always getting 0:

```
double empBasePay = (RegHours * empHourlyRate) + (otHours * empHourlyRate * 1.5);
```

As `RegHours` and `otHours` equal 0, you might as well write:

```
double empBasePay = 0;
```

And as the rest of the method is based on the base value of `empBasePay`, which is 0, your method will always return 0.

Comment: Ok let me take a look..ill comment out the return statements in each if and else if one first..

Comment: You need to comment out the ones in the `if`, `else` and in the `while` too.

Comment: ok did that thank you talnicolas. It seems to be still returning back zero...hmm.  The only return statements I have now are at the end.  This is where if none of the while statements are true and all of the hours of the 7 days on the timecard are filled then it does the check to verify if the hours are greater than 34 hours.  Those are the only return statements left now.  So are my values not being saved in the variables properly perhaps?

Comment: @wonu and by the way, where does `timeCard` come from?

Comment: That is a good point.  I'm not even sure I am getting in.  Yes I'm using NeBeans IDE 7.0.1..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8414/discussion-between-wonu-and-talnicolas)

Comment: Okay so part two on this.  I restructured the code on this but now I can't figure out a way to return back the empWeeklyPay without initializing it to zero.  And if I initialize it to zero then my pay will always be zero?  Can anyone think of anything I can do?

Comment: To resolve this issue, I seperated the different sections and I just put the while loop by itself to calculate the regular hours and overtime hours:

while(i < getTimeCard().NUMDAYS)
    {
    //grabbing the overtime and reghours and storing them
    double otHours = 0;
    double regHours = 0;
    otHours += getTimeCard().getHoursByDay(i);
    regHours += getTimeCard().getHoursByDay(i) - otHours;
    sumOtHours += otHours;
    sumRegHours += regHours;
    i++;
    }